# mod rewrite to change the domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to change the domain of my urls, Parent URL is something like

```
http://abc.def.com/123123132/abcvalue
```

I have a rule like

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc\.def\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://efg.com/dd/as/$1 [L]
```

this is changing the domain but it is putting the old domain in new url too. Something like

```
https://efg.com/dd/as/http://abc.def.com/123123132/abcvalue
```

Need help on this. Thanks

Edit:- Complete htaccess is

```
    # php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php74” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php74 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>


# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
RewriteEngine On
#### PrintNinja unique redirects
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^printninja.com$ [NC]    
RewriteRule ^learn/(.*) /printing-resource-center/ [NC,L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^digital-downloads/(.*) /printing-resource-center/ [NC,L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^resources/(.*) /printing-resource-center/ [NC,L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^pricing\/(.*)$ https://printninja.com/calculator/$1 [L]
#### Begin Uploader rewrites
# printingupload.com/files-submited/*   --redirect to ->   https://printninja.com/calculator/files-submited/*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?printingupload\.com$
RewriteRule ^printingupload\.com/files-submited\/(.*)$ https://printninja.com/calculator/files-submited/$1 [L]
# printingupload.com/invalid-order/*   --redirect to ->  https://printninja.com/calculator/invalid-order/*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?printingupload\.com$
RewriteRule ^printingupload\.com/invalid-order\/(.*)$ https://printninja.com/calculator/invalid-order/$1 [L]
# printingupload.com/*   --redirect to ->   https://printninja.com/calculator/products/upload_proofing/* (this rule must appear after the other printingupload.com/* rules)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?printingupload\.com$
RewriteRule ^printingupload\.com\/(.*)$ https://printninja.com/calculator/products/upload_proofing/$1 [L]
# submit.printingupload.com/*   --redirect to ->   https://printninja.com/calculator/submit_proofing/*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^submit\.printingupload\.com$
RewriteRule ^submit\.printingupload\.com\/(.*)$ http://printninja.com/calculator/submit_proofing/$1 [L]
# proofs.printingupload.com/approved/*   --redirect to ->   https://printninja.com/calculator/status/approved/*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^proofs\.printingupload\.com$
RewriteRule ^approved\/(.*)$ https://printninja.com/calculator/status/approved/$1 [L]
# proofs.printingupload.com/rejected/*   --redirect to ->   http://staging.printninja.com/calculator/status/rejected/*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^proofs\.printingupload\.com$
RewriteRule ^rejected\/(.*)$ https://printninja.com/calculator/status/rejected/$1 [L]
# proofs.printingupload.com/*   --redirect to ->   http://staging.printninja.com/calculator/rackfile/*

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^proofs\.printingupload\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://printninja.com/calculator/rackfile/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your attempts, could you please do let us know if you any other rules also before OR after these posted rules also?

Comment: Yes! There are.

Comment: Ohh ok, then please share complete htaccess of your in your question. So that we can get clear picture of where it's not working

Comment: Edited the question. I am referring to the final rule.

Answer (score 2):

Have your htaccess Rules file in following manner, please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
    # php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php74” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php74 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>


# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
RewriteEngine On
#### PrintNinja unique redirects
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^proofs\.printingupload\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ https://printninja.com/calculator/rackfile/$1 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^printninja.com$ [NC]    
RewriteRule ^learn/(.*) /printing-resource-center/ [NC,L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^digital-downloads/(.*) /printing-resource-center/ [NC,L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^resources/(.*) /printing-resource-center/ [NC,L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^pricing\/(.*)$ https://printninja.com/calculator/$1 [L]
#### Begin Uploader rewrites
# printingupload.com/files-submited/*   --redirect to ->   https://printninja.com/calculator/files-submited/*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?printingupload\.com$
RewriteRule ^printingupload\.com/files-submited\/(.*)$ https://printninja.com/calculator/files-submited/$1 [L]
# printingupload.com/invalid-order/*   --redirect to ->  https://printninja.com/calculator/invalid-order/*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?printingupload\.com$
RewriteRule ^printingupload\.com/invalid-order\/(.*)$ https://printninja.com/calculator/invalid-order/$1 [L]
# printingupload.com/*   --redirect to ->   https://printninja.com/calculator/products/upload_proofing/* (this rule must appear after the other printingupload.com/* rules)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?printingupload\.com$
RewriteRule ^printingupload\.com\/(.*)$ https://printninja.com/calculator/products/upload_proofing/$1 [L]
# submit.printingupload.com/*   --redirect to ->   https://printninja.com/calculator/submit_proofing/*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^submit\.printingupload\.com$
RewriteRule ^submit\.printingupload\.com\/(.*)$ http://printninja.com/calculator/submit_proofing/$1 [L]
# proofs.printingupload.com/approved/*   --redirect to ->   https://printninja.com/calculator/status/approved/*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^proofs\.printingupload\.com$
RewriteRule ^approved\/(.*)$ https://printninja.com/calculator/status/approved/$1 [L]
# proofs.printingupload.com/rejected/*   --redirect to ->   http://staging.printninja.com/calculator/status/rejected/*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^proofs\.printingupload\.com$
RewriteRule ^rejected\/(.*)$ https://printninja.com/calculator/status/rejected/$1 [L]
# proofs.printingupload.com/*   --redirect to ->   http://staging.printninja.com/calculator/rackfile/*
```

Comment: That didn't fixed the issue.

Comment: @nOmi, ok, what's happening now?

Comment: it is same as it was.

Comment: @nOmi, could you please do let me know on my above question here.

Comment: @nOmi, Hi, could you please do let me know if these rules have worked for you? OR you have found any other solution for this one? Thank you,